# sql merge two fields where NULL could be in any of the fields

Tags: sql-server, merge

I currently have two tables with people's names in the first column of both tables. But the situation is the two tables have got different names in them. In order to keep information of both tables I used `FULL OUTER JOIN` so as we can imagine SQL gives me a table like this:

```
   Name1  |   Name2 | ...
    Mary  |   Mary  | ...
    NULL  |   Jack  | ...
    Jim   |   Jim   | ...
   Martin |   NULL  | ...
   Bella  |   Bella | ...
    Bex   |   Bex   | ...
```

What I want is just keeping one column and if there is NULL in one of the column the name on the other column should be used. So ideally the result I want should be like this:

```
    Name  | ...
    Mary  | ...
    Jack  | ...
    Jim   | ...
   Martin | ...
   Bella  | ...
    Bex   | ...
```

Is there a function to help merge two columns together?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `COALESCE(Name1, Name2)`

Comment: You can use ISNULL(column1, column2). When column1 is null, column2 value will be used.

Comment: Thanks guys. I never imagine this could be so easy. I was thinking if I should write if else case before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function (or rather: expression) is called [`COALESCE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx). It takes a variable number of arguments and returns the first one that is not null:

```
COALESCE(Name1, Name2)
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukas Eder. This is really handy